# MR_findFirstWithPredicate in illegal context

Tags: core-data, ios7, magicalrecord, magicalrecord-2.2

In the following code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                                    cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    Person *person = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    label.text = person.fullName;

    UIImageView *iv = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    NSPredicate *pr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"person == %@", person];
    Image *image = [Image MR_findFirstWithPredicate:pr inContext:person.managedObjectContext];
    iv.image = image.image ? image.image : [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"];
    return cell;
}
```

This line

```
Image *image = [Image MR_findFirstWithPredicate:pr inContext:person.managedObjectContext];
```

is using illegal context.
I tried to use local context instead of `person.managedObjectContext`, but it still illegal.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you doing this at all? It looks like a Person object has an Image relationship. Just use:

```
imageView.image = person.image ?: [UIImage imageNamed:@"default"];
```

No need to do more fetches that will just make the code harder to read and also slow down your app.

Comment: Person has images, NSSet type.

Comment: Even so, your predicate as specified here, is going to return a set of results. Why not then just use [person.images anyObject]?